# Avoid setInterval/setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I have the following problem: in my function with `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` I repeat an action with an increment in `i` endlessly. Because of the delay of setInterval or setTimeout (i think it's the latter), after some time the script stops working correctly, several tasks will happen simultaneously.

The script is used on WhatsApp Web an clicks through the first 16 contacts, for each checking the online status. It then prints a log if the contact is online. The problem is the following: after aomw time (3h or so) the interval repeats itself before the old function has finished. So i get 14,1,15,2,16,3,1,4... instead of 1,2,3,5...

```
setInterval(function () {
    function writeNext(i) {
        if (i == 17)
            return;

        setTimeout(function () {
            writeNext(i + 1);
            selectContact(`${i}`)

            if (document.getElementsByClassName("O90ur")[0] !== undefined) {
                var online = document.getElementsByClassName("O90ur")[0].innerHTML
                    if (online == "online") {
                        console.log(`${i-1}`)
                    };
            }

        }, 1250);
    }

    writeNext(1);
}, 20000);
```

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: @Karan It's recursive: `writeNext(i + 1)`

Comment: Every 20 seconds you're creating a new `writeNext()` function which calls itself, which calls itself, which calls itself, ...

Comment: What is it, that you want to achieve?

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by 'script stops working correctly'. What was the actual issue? And what were you trying to do. It would help people answer it better

Comment: @Andreas So what? It only calls itself until `i` hits 17. As `16 * 1250 = 20000`, I don't see the problem with this code. OP, please provide an MVCE and describe your problem more clearly.

Comment: @shinobi I updated the description. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timer for `setTimout` is very close to `20000 / 17`.  If the timing of the recursion is not precise, you will start to see overlap where the next `setInterval` starts calling new timeouts before all 17 of the old timeouts are done. Also timers in javascript are not guaranteed to be accurate  to high resolution.

If you just want something to run continuously on a loop, consider just using `setInterval` and calculate `i % 17`. For example:

```js
let i = 1
setInterval(function () {
     // do stuff with `i`
     console.log(i)
     i = i % 17 + 1
}, 400);

It will be easier to debug and understand and won't have any chance of overlap.
```